# Remove all markers from mapbox when clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, button, mapbox, marker

I know that there is a command "marker.remove()" which allows me to remove the marker right after I added it to the map. The following code is part of a for-loop:

```
      var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
      .setLngLat(markeryellowhalf.geometry.coordinates)
      .addTo(map);
      //marker.remove();
```

But my idea is to click a button that calls a new function. And the first thing this function should do is to remove (or hide) all markers.

With which command can I start this function? Of course, "marker.remove()" does not work here.

This is my map object:

```
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({    
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9',
    center: [30, 0],
    zoom: 1.2,
    // pitch: 45,
    // bearing: -17.6,
    container: 'map'
});
```

Then myFunction1...

```
function myFunction1(){
.
.
.
switch (statusArray1[c]){
    case "existing [completed]":
    geojson.features.forEach(function(markeryellow) {

      // create a HTML element for each feature
      var el = document.createElement('div');
      el.className = 'markeryellow';

      // make a markeryellow for each feature and add to the map
    var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
      .setLngLat(markeryellow.geometry.coordinates)
      .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }) // add popups
      .setHTML('<h3>' + markeryellow.properties.title + '</h3><p>' + markeryellow.properties.description + '</p>'))
      .addTo(map);
      //marker.remove();
    });
    break;
    case "under construction [on hold]":
    case "under construction [foundation work]":
    case "under construction [frame assembly]":
    case "under construction [topped out]":
    geojson.features.forEach(function(markeryellowhalf) {

      // create a HTML element for each feature
      var el = document.createElement('div');
      el.className = 'markeryellowhalf';

      // make a markeryellowhalf for each feature and add to the map
        var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
      .setLngLat(markeryellowhalf.geometry.coordinates)
      .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }) // add popups
      .setHTML('<h3>' + markeryellowhalf.properties.title + '</h3><p>' + markeryellowhalf.properties.description + '</p>'))
      .addTo(map);
      //marker.remove();
    });



    break;
}
```

}

}

An then comes myFunction2() {...
}

Answer (score 1):

you can try this like this:

```
map.on('click', function (e) {

   //define that to delete or todo here

});
```

but for more accurate anwser i need more info, like `html/css` and your `map object`